# Multiple column sorting - Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to sort multiple columns on Jqgrid..But its not sorting at all. I am using below code.

`multiSort : true,`
`sortname: 'orderNo asc, cd',`
`sortorder: 'desc',`

How to do that? Is any other way to do that?

I also tried below one

```
 $('#OrderGrid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'orderNo', true, 'asc')
 .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc');
```

But no luck still now...

Comment: You should provide some additional details on your `jqGrid` options. Jsfiddle would be even nicer. In documentation it's said that _jqGrid works this way only if datatype is set to local. Otherwise, the sortname string is sent in the sidx URL parameter and the server side has to take care of the sorting._ So what is your `data` type?

Comment: @user2160534 What framework are you using? sorting is on the server side

Comment: datatype is set to local..I am not doing server side sorting..

Comment: I am using jquery jqgrid sorting  only

Comment: Do you really need to change **dynamically** the sort order or you creates the grid with unsorted data and want to display the data sorted by multiple columns?

Comment: I want to sort the multiple columns dynamically. I tried many ways..But could not sort it

Answer (score 5):

To set `"desc"` order one have to call `sortGrid` **twice**:

```
$('#OrderGrid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'orderNo', true, 'asc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc');
```

For example if you need to set sort direction of both `orderNo` and `cd` columns to `desc` you should use

```
$('#OrderGrid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'orderNo', true, 'desc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'orderNo', true, 'desc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc');
```

Be sure that you set `multiSort` option of jqGrid to `true` before calling of `sortGrid`:

```
$('#OrderGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {multiSort: true})
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'orderNo', true, 'asc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'cd', true, 'desc');
```

Alternatively you can don't use `sortGrid` at all. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultiSortLoad1.htm) demonstrates the approach. It uses the following code

```
setSorting.call($grid[0], "name", "desc");
setSorting.call($grid[0], "invdate", "asc");
$grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
    multiSort: true,
    sortname: "name desc, invdate asc"
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

where `setSorting` function are defined as below

```
var setSorting = function (colName, sortOrder) {
    var $self = $(this),
        colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        headers = $self[0].grid.headers,
        showSortIconsInAllCols = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "viewsortcols")[0],
        cmLength = colModel.length,
        cm,
        $sortSpan,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < cmLength; i++) {
        cm = colModel[i];
        if (cm.name === colName) {
            cm.lso = String(sortOrder).toLowerCase() === "desc" ? "desc" : "asc";
        }
        $sortSpan = $(headers[i].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico");
        if (showSortIconsInAllCols || cm.lso) {
            $sortSpan.show();
            if (cm.lso) {
                $sortSpan.find(">span.ui-icon-" + cm.lso)
                    .removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
            }
        }
    }
};
```